# Window.Open POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, popup, window.open

I have a link which when clicked I open a window with window.open like below.

```
 window.open("edit.jsp?clientId=" + clientId + "&eventId=" + eventId , 'height=600,width=800,scrollbars=1,location:no,menubar:no,resizable=1,status:no,toolbar:no');
```

I dont want the parameter to pass here instead I want to something like post so people cant copy url .

Comment: This questions looks similar: [window.open post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951768/window-open-and-pass-parameters-by-post-method-problem)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot trigger a javascript popup and then force a post request.

Three options:

1. Trigger a POST form with `target="_blank"` using javascript (but this doesn't allow you to disable interface elements such as the menu bar).
2. Open a popup locally, but don't specify a url. Use the result of window.open to alter the document to generate a form, which you'd then post.

   ```
   var myWindow = window.open("", "", "height=600,width=800,scrollbars=1,location=no,menubar=no,resizable=1,status=no,toolbar=no");
   myWindow.document.write("Write a form here and then later on trigger it");
   ```
3. You really shouldn't do any of this. If it's bad for users to copy urls, there's a flaw in your application design.
4. **Added after edit**: Use the 'empty window' approach, but instead of writing a form and triggering it, do a an `XMLHTTPRequest` (with POST) in the parent. The result of this request can be used to populate the child-window.

Answer (score 7):

Beside AJAX (jquery.load()), which I would use myself - how about the following approach:

```
<form method="post" action="edit.jsp" target="_blank">
      <input type="hidden" name="clientId" value="88"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="eventId" value="2"/>
</form>
```

target = _blank will actually open a new window /tab the posted data will be processed in.
Unfortunatelly you can hardly control the new windows appearance.

Answer (score 0):

How about implementing a model popup window using a div? You can make an http post call to load the content of that div/model popup. You can use jQuery load() method to load the content of the div as well.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Some other model popup plugins are here

http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

http://fancybox.net/