# html form target _blank browser not allowed

Tags: jquery, ajax, popup

I need to send a post request to paypal, but before sending the form I need to verify some inputs and the paypal page must be opened in a new tab or window (doesn't matter). I can't send the request in the same window because in the main page I have background ajax callbacks. So the ideea is can I send the request in a new window or tab?

In all major browesers this isn't allowed, browser keep blocking the request.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank" id="paypal_form">
<input type='hidden' name='some_value' id='some_value' value='151' />
</form>

<div id='button_submit' onClick="verify_paypal_form();">SUBMIT !</div>
```

And now the ajax part:

```
function verify_paypal_form(){
   $.post('verify.php', { someValue : 'FOO' },
   function(data){
      if( data == 'OKAY' ) $('#paypal_form').submit();
   });
}
```

Comment: You can use Iframe instead. set the target of the form to that iframe using id.

Answer (score 1):

set the target of form to iframe and try it. you can show that iframe as a content of new tab as well.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="myFrame" id="paypal_form">
<input type='hidden' name='some_value' id='some_value' value='151' />
</form>

<div id='button_submit' onClick="verify_paypal_form();">SUBMIT !</div>
<iframe id="myFrame" ...... set other attributes as required....></iframe>
```

Comment: I don't understand it. Conent of iframe? I need to send the post request to paypal in a new window or tab.

Answer (score 1):

You could open a new window with JS too and then use the solution of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5555021/1087848):

```
$("#paypal_form").submit(function() {
    var newWin = window.open("", "", ""); // SPecify your window attributes here, but no URL
    // do an XMLHTPPRequest and document.write the result to the new window:
    var winDoc = doAJAXAndReturnOtherPagesSource();
    newWin.document.write(winDoc);
});
```