# How to replace window.open(...) with a POST

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have some code that runs a `window.open(urlWithGetParams)` line. As far as I'm aware, this is going to force me to use a `GET` request. I would like to do this with a POST request. Is there a workaround for this?

I'm not married to `window.open()`, either. I'm open to just about any alternative that allows me to spawn a new window via a POST request instead of a GET.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554896/window-open-post or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951768/window-open-and-pass-parameters-by-post-method-problem

Comment: The operation in the "duplicate" won't really work for me - I'd have to get those parameters into the new window somehow, and that would require sending them via... what? A GET request? O_o

Answer (score 100, accepted):

In fact I made a small "library" for this, open in POST a new window :

```
// Arguments :
//  verb : 'GET'|'POST'
//  target : an optional opening target (a name, or "_blank"), defaults to "_self"
window.io = {
    open: function(verb, url, data, target){
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.action = url;
        form.method = verb;
        form.target = target || "_self";
        if (data) {
            for (var key in data) {
                var input = document.createElement("textarea");
                input.name = key;
                input.value = typeof data[key] === "object"
                    ? JSON.stringify(data[key])
                    : data[key];
                form.appendChild(input);
            }
        }
        form.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
        document.body.removeChild(form);
    }
};
```

Example :

```
io.open('POST', 'fileServer.jsp', {request: {key:"42", cols:[2, 3, 34]}});
```

To open in a new window, set the `target` parameter :

```
io.open('POST', someURL, someArgs, 'newwin');
```

or to ensure it's a new window/tab each time :

```
io.open('POST', someURL, someArgs, '_blank');
```

Comment: I like it, and it does run a post, but it doesn't open a new Window (at least, in IE 9.0.8112.16421

Comment: @corsiKa It does open a new window if you set the target parameter : `open('POST', url, {}, 'newwin')`

Comment: Beautiful! I made it `var reportWindowName = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,9);` so that if I click it multiple times, each report opens in a new window (well, probably :-))

Comment: @corsiKa Simply use `'_blank'` as target to open in a new window/tab each time.

Comment: Nice approach - just what I was looking for, and works perfectly!

Comment: Does not support line breaks from text areas, since the transporting element created is a regular `<input>`.

Comment: @RadGH +1 As I use it only with JSON, I hadn't thought about that. I edited to use a textarea (untested).

Comment: A textarea does fix the linebreak issue, thanks for updating!

Comment: Another way to solve the multi-line problem is to use `encodeURIComponent` on the string(ified JSON data). The you may also use a `hidden` input type then.

Comment: Just a note: You may want to end with:

    document.body.removeChild(form);

Comment: This is awesome!! one comment is you should make sure you also don't have any keys named "submit" - had some issues with that.

Comment: +1, it's best to dispose that temporary form element. one method is to add `formElement.outerHTML = "";` after submitting

Comment: i was not able to retrieve the data through PHP from the target page, what I'm missing?

Comment: Question: does this support complex object parameter? It seems like in your example you use complex object, but when i do it, it doesnt work!

Comment: @DenysSéguret I am facing some issue , if my request data is something like - `data={reqName:'test' reqValuesList:[{name:'req1',value:'reqValue1'},{name:'req2',value:'reqValue2'}]}` in this case `reqName` is sent to server side properly , but `reqValuesList` is showing null. Can you help me out on this.

Comment: What should be the input for the *data* for the function ? e.g. I want to send the &Type=dog&Name=doggy, what should be the format for it ?

Answer (score 6):

What I do is that I do a javascript AJAX post and then I take the content that I get back and place it into a new window.

Something like this (using jQuery, but you can use any AJAX implementation):

```
$.post(URL, DATA, function(d){
    var new_window = window.open();
    $(new_window.document.body).append(d);
});
```

Comment: I should point out that I tried this and it worked minus one thing: something about crystal reports (which is what I was doing this for) wouldn't pass the parameters. It may have been how I implemented the suggestion, though.

Comment: I use this suggested code in Chrome version 38 and blocked by popup blocker!