# Open Popup with post data

Tags: javascript, php, post, popup

I got a javascript for send value to a Popup but only works with `$_GET['value']` because when a change to `$_POST['value']` it shows this message

```
Notice: Undefined index: value in C:\wamp\www\corti\presupuestos\precio.php on line 10
```

this is the javascript code

```
function envia(){
    var co = $("#codart").val();
    var pag = 'precio.php?value='+co;
    window.open(pag,'Popwin','height=400, width=400');
}
```

this is the button

`<img src="../png/buscar.png" height="16" width="16" onClick="javascript: envia();">`

and this is de popup php file

`<?php 
$c=$_POST['value'];
echo $c;
?>`

thanks for you help and your time

Comment: Ah, this question has the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554896/window-open-post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Window.open and pass parameters by post method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951768/window-open-and-pass-parameters-by-post-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because `$_POST` can't read url strings query. and you are sending your variable in url string query.
that's why you have to use `$_GET` in your case.

Otherwise, you need to use `ajax` such as mentioned in many websites articles to perform post.
and here's one for example:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost.shtml