# Open the response of POST in a new popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-post

Below pasted code I use for posting data. The response opens in a new tab.

```
GF.SubmitForm = function (url, params, target) {
    // create form string using array push and join
    var form = ['<form method="POST" action="', url, '" target="', target, '">'];
    for (var key in params)
        form.push('<input type="hidden" name="', key, '" value="', params[key], '"/>');
    form.push('</form>');
    jQuery(form.join('')).appendTo('body')[0].submit();
}
```

What should I do to make this code open, the response data, in a new popup window.

Replaced the last line of code in the above function with the below pasted code but didn't work

```
 jQuery(form.join('')).appendTo('body')[0].submit(function () {
        window.open(url,target,"menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to open a new window with the [response from the POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554896/window-open-post) using `window.open()`.  Using Ajax is an option that might help you avoid side effects for other callers of `GE.SubmitForm()`

```
GF.SubmitForm = function (url, params, target) {
        if (target === 'newwindow')
        {
            var paramsString = '';
            for (var key in params)
                paramsString += key + '=' + params[key] + '&';
            var urlCopy = url;
            jQuery.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: 'post',
                data: paramsString,
                dataType: 'html',
                url: urlCopy
            }).done(function(data){
                var newWindow = window.open(urlCopy,target,"menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");
                newWindow.document.write(data);
            });
            return;
        }

        // create form string using array push and join
        var form = ['<form method="POST" action="', url, '" target="', target, '">'];
        for (var key in params)
            form.push('<input type="hidden" name="', key, '" value="', params[key], '"/>');
        form.push('</form>');
        jQuery(form.join('')).appendTo('body')[0].submit();
};
```

Forgive the magic string `newwindow` that would need to be the `target` value.  You get the idea.  You could also overload the function with a boolean for opening a new window, then call the original 3-arg function if false, and use the ajax if true.