# How pass javascript object to webmethod

Tags: javascript, c#, parameter-passing, json

I want to simple file download method.

My class is:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string StringParam { get; set; }
    public int IntParam{ get; set; }
}
```

My Web Method:

```
public void MyExport(TestClass exportArg)
{
     //do something
}
```

I can pass javascript object to web method as TestClass object with ajax

```
var params = {};
params['StringParam '] = 'asd';
params['IntParam'] = 5;

$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Home/MyExport',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(params)
        });
```

But when i try this with window.open exportArg parameter is null. How can i pass a javascript object to web method with window.open

```
window.open('Home/MyExport?exportArg=' + JSON.stringify(params));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method is expecting a `POST` request, by appending the value onto the query string and calling `window.open` you're executing a `GET` request.

You cant execute a `POST` with `window.open`. There are a few workarounds, you can find them in this question & answers: [Window.Open POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554896/window-open-post)