# I want my window.open with a post request in jQuery

Tags: javascript

This is my expression which I am using

```
window.open(someURL?filename="+filename+"&drid="+drid,"_self","");
```

I need to send the data using the post method and not the query string.

Please help me out.

Comment: `window.open` uses a GET request, not a POST

Comment: Maybe one of these will help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=window.open+POST

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5555021/2181514) suggests: POST form with target="_blank" (but will go to a new tab these days, not an antiquated popup window)