# Post a Form to Popup window not to the parent

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I want to post a forma poupup window. Problem is, the form posts successfully but It also posts on the parent window. I want to submit the formonly in popup window

```
'<input type= button value ="Submit Form" onclick="adNetworkForm()" >
<script>
function adNetworkForm(){ 
targetUrl = "http://somesite.com"    
    var myForm = document.createElement('form');
    myForm.method = 'post';
    //myForm.action = targetUrl;        

    var inpt1 = document.createElement('input');
    inpt1.setAttribute('name','a');
    inpt1.setAttribute('type', 'hidden')
    inpt1.value = "1"; 

    var inpt2 = document.createElement('input');
    inpt2.setAttribute('name','b');
    inpt2.setAttribute('type', 'hidden')
    inpt2.value = 2; 
    myForm.appendChild(inpt1);
    myForm.appendChild(inpt2);
    document.body.appendChild(myForm);
    myForm.submit(popitup(targetUrl));
    document.body.removeChild(myForm);
}

 function popitup(url) {
newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=600,width=500');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
return false;
}

</script>​'
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Eusb/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Window.open and pass parameters by post method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951768/window-open-and-pass-parameters-by-post-method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could assign an onsubmit event handler to the form to call a function which pops open a new window when the form is submitted and targets the form to that window, like:

```
<form action="..." method="post" onsubmit="some_popup_post(this);">
<!-- form fields etc here -->
</form>
```

And js code would be:

```
function some_popup_post(form) {
    window.open('', 'formpopup', 'width=400,height=400,resizeable,scrollbars');
    form.target = 'formpopup';
}
```

Do you mean something like this..