# How to pass .html() value from JavaScript to CodeIgniter controller?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have a print button and when it is clicked the following JavaScript function must be triggered.

```
$('.print').click(function(){
    var htmlval=$('.pop_reciept').html();
    window.open('http://localhost/ccccccc/xxxxxxx/pdf/'+htmlval,'_blank');                                  
});
```

`htmlval` contains the HTML of elements with the class `pop_reciept`, and then I pass this to the `pdf` controller:

```
public function pdf($val){
   echo $val;

   return false;

}
```

I want the HTML content need to displayed. But it is not, and instead I see the error

> The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Please help or suggest a better way to do this.

Comment: I'd believe the [`input` class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) automatically filters the input. Not sure what'd be the best solution around that.

Comment: Try `htmlval = encodeURIComponent(htmlval);`

Answer (score 2):

The size of url is limited to 8kb at most servers, great chunks of html code can easily exceed it.
Sending a POST request instead solves the problem of disallowed characters too.
You can find a solution for this here: [Window.open and pass parameters by post method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951768/window-open-and-pass-parameters-by-post-method-problem)

Answer (score 0):

add the special characters to variable `$config['permitted_uri_chars']`

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_=+-';
```

in your config.php