# hide url and parameters when ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following ajax js code. The ../menu/solonreport.jsp return a url link like [this](http://members.solae.gr/reporting/?report=Liquidations/LD_Forms_B4Admin.rpt&prompt0=2014-2015&init=xls) connect to a local report server and create a excel report.

The  `window.open(json.url)` open the link in new window but I dont want to show the link and more the parameters to the user.

Is this possible?

```
function getEventTarget(e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   return e.target || e.srcElement;
}

var ul = document.getElementById('menureport');
ul.onclick = function(event) {
   var target = getEventTarget(event);
   var reportid = target.id;
   var reporttype = target.innerHTML;
   alert(reportid);
   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: '../menu/solonreport.jsp',
       data: {
           Wreportid: reportid,
           Wreporttype: reporttype
       },
       async: false,
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(json) {
           window.open(json.url);
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: have a look here for some brain food... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951768/window-open-and-pass-parameters-by-post-method

Comment: andy mccullough the url report created in soloreport.jsp and may be have a different number of parameters

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
window.open(json.url,'PDF','directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no');
```

But this depends on the browser how it handles this.

Comment: the json.url returns and xlsx reports and not workig in google chrome