# Symfony - BinaryFileResponse returns a ResponseHeader, but no file

Tags: php, file, symfony, pdf, response

currently trying to serve a static PDF file that is not within the web directory ($reasons).

I applied

```
$filepath = $this->getTargetFile($level, $name);

$response = new BinaryFileResponse($filepath);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
$response->setContentDisposition(
    ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE,
    $filename
);
return $response;
```

and Profiler shows that there is a Response with correct headers, but there is no document view and no download prompt whatsoever. Is there something I am missing?

```
/** Get target file */
public function getTargetFile($level, $name)
{
    return $this->kernel->locateResource($staticPath . $level . '/' . $name);
}
```

Comment: the `$filepath` value is correct?

Comment: `$filepath` was correct, yes. I think the problem was that there was no actual environment for the received data to be parsed into (i.e. no browser-based PDF reader), and in the end I had to override that manually via Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Some nerves were spent, but:

I created a form via JavaScript and submitted the needed parameters into a new window ([thanks to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951768/window-open-and-pass-parameters-by-post-method)), that made the job. If anyone has a "cleaner" solution, I'm open to suggestions :)