# Form not submitted properly to the right page when using JS window.open() and submit() to open a new window on button click and pass data through POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, post

I want to open a new window (not tab) on button click and pass arguments to the new page opened in the new window.

My SO search took me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951768/window-open-and-pass-parameters-by-post-method#answer-3951843), and I followed it. I am facing the following problems:

1. The new window that opens does Not get the title of the page from the  HTML `<title>` tag in `secondIndex.php`.
2. The data I am trying to pass in the `hidden` `input` field of the form does not seem to be passed to the page opening on button click.
3. The newly opened page should have the URL like `http://something/something/secondIndex.php` because that is the value of the `action` attribute in the `form` tag. But it rather says `about:blank`.

**The question is why, where am I going wrong, and how do I fix these problems?**

[image]

**index.php:**

```
<?php

$dataToPass = array(
        "A" => array(
                1 => array(
                        "id" => 1,
                        "secondId" => 2,
                        "thirdId" => 3
                )
        ),


        "B" => array(
                1 => array(
                        "id" => 4,
                        "secondId" => 5,
                        "thirdId" => 6
                ),
                2 => array(
                        "id" => 7,
                        "secondId" => 8,
                        "thirdId" => 9
                )
        ),


        "C" => array(
                1 => array(
                        "id" => 10,
                        "secondId" => 11,
                        "thirdId" => 12
                )
        )

);


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="scripts.js"></script>

</head>







<body>


<form id="aForm" action="secondIndex.php" method="post" target="TheWindow" >
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenData" value="<?php echo json_encode($dataToPass); ?>" />
</form>



<button id="aButton">Click Me</button>

</body>
```

**secondIndex.php:**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Data</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php 

        if (isset($_POST["hiddenData"])) {
            print_r($_POST["hiddenData"]);
        }

    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

**scripts.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#aButton").click(function() {
        alert("#aButton clicked.");//check

        window.open("", "TheWindow", "width=500px, height=500px");
        document.getElementById("#aForm").submit();
    });

});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window