# How to submit a form to a page such that this new page opens in a new window (rather than a new tab)?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

This is a follow-up question of [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327872/form-not-submitted-properly-to-the-right-page-when-using-js-window-open-and-su).

I need to open a new Window on button click, and pass data to the new page.

One way is to have a form constituting `hidden` fields (containing the data I want to pass to the new page) and submit this form using JS in the click listener of the button.

So far, this seems smooth. I will assign the `action` attribute of `<form>` a value of the URL of the page I want to open on button click. Then I will submit this form through JS in the click listener of the button.

The challenge/question-I-am-asking-here is that how do I open the new page (the page which will open on form submit) in a new window?

Comment: `target="_blank"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<form action="#otherpage" method="post" target="_blank">

    <-- form fields here -->

</form>
```