# "Converting" javascript variable (String) value into PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php

I am using window.open() method to open a new window and passing a Javascript variable (String) using localStorage.setItem() method.
In the new window that's opened, I retrive the passed variable using localStorage.getItem() method.
Now I need this variable for an SQL query using PHP,
something like "SELECT rowname from tablename WHERE id = TheJSVariable"

But I couldn't find any where a solution for it.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: How are you sending the query to PHP? Using Ajax or a form?

Comment: send this value via ajax to the same page or to the different php page and using $_POST get that value (use ajax post method)

Comment: Manngo: I am not using Ajax or a form, only a simple query and then mysqli_query to fetch results.
Alive to Die: How can I send a Javascript string value using ajax post in a window.open method? Any link? thanks  (I'm new to this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening with window.open you can add your parameter as common get parameter. i.e.:

window.open ("mysite.com/page.php?param=123");

And then at page.php you can read param value with:

```
$param = $_GET['param'];
```

***update:***

If you want to make post request you could add (hidden) form with form fields holding the values you want to pass and submit that form from code. Something like:

```
<form id="TheForm" method="post" action="test.asp" target="TheWindow">
<input type="hidden" name="something" value="something" />
<input type="hidden" name="more" value="something" />
<input type="hidden" name="other" value="something" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.open('', 'TheWindow');
document.getElementById('TheForm').submit();
</script>
```

[Window.open and pass parameters by post method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951768/window-open-and-pass-parameters-by-post-method)

Comment: Thank you, and a few questions:
(1)If the param is a variable, i.e var x = "String"; Should I type window.open ("mysite.com/page.php?param=" + x);?
(2)If I want a POST instead of GET, what would be the way to write it using window.open?

Comment: updated my answer, and yes, window.open should be generated something like you wrote in your comment

Comment: Thank you! 
By the way, my mistake,  I have been using window.location instead of window.open, so I should switch all window.location to window.open, right? because window.location does not have the capability of adding parameters? Or does it? :)

Comment: I think that you can pass get parameters with both. Google is your friend! :)

Comment: Got it! Thanks mate!