# Send POST request in javascript popup window

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit

I'm trying to send POST request to javascript pop-up. I was able to do it using a new tab, but would like to do using a pop-up.

```
    var mapForm = document.createElement("form");
    mapForm.target = target;
    mapForm.method = method;
    mapForm.action = url;

    if (data) {
        for (var key in data) {
            var input = document.createElement("textarea");
            input.name = key;
            input.value = data[key];
            mapForm.appendChild(input);
        }
    }
    mapForm.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(mapForm);

    mapForm.submit();
```

Comment: What did you put as the target of the form?

Comment: i gave "_blank" as the target @ADyson

Comment: Did you mean [window-open-and-pass-parameters-by-post-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951768/window-open-and-pass-parameters-by-post-method)

Comment: @DipanshuMahla yes i have tried that way, but if i use both window.open and form.submit(), its opening in windoww and pop-up

Comment: Why are you doing `form.submit()`.

Comment: I'm sending data from form to access them in server side @DipanshuMahla

Comment: You can open the popup window after submitting the form.

Comment: Tried that way too, but the popup doesn't get the form data. also a window and a popup gets opened

Answer (score 0):

Heading

```js
$(".post-btn").click(function() {
  var name = $(this).attr('id');
  var post_number = name.match(/\d+/g);
  console.log(post_number);
  var post_id = 'team' + post_number;
  console.log(post_id);
  var img_link = $("#" + post_id + " img").attr('src');
  var post_heading = $("#"+post_id+" .post-heading").text();
  var post_content = $("#"+post_id+" .post-content").text();
  console.log(img_link)
  console.log(post_heading)
  console.log(post_content)
});

function togglePopup() {
  $(".pop-up").toggle(); 
}
```