# js post form data to http from https

Tags: javascript, http, https

As title.
The system I'm developing is at https://A.com/ .  I need to open a new window at http://A.com/mth and pass a parameters (an array of strings, already joined with commas like K1,K2,K3,...,Kn),just the same as opening a new window shows http://B.com/mth?keys=K1,K2,K3,...,Kn .  But I can't pass by query string because it may make the url too long.

I use the post method at the form with my parameter in it by the way just like  [Window.open and pass parameters by post method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951768/window-open-and-pass-parameters-by-post-method)

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" action="http://A.com/mth" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="keys" id="iptkey" />
</form>
```

And then, JS about POST....

```
var f=document.getElementById("form1");
f.keys.value=keys.join(",");
f.submit();
```

I failed when I saw a message: "The page at https://A.com was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form that targets an insecure endpoints http://A.com/mth......."
How could I use JavaScript to achieve my goal and solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you need to downgrade from HTTPS to HTTP? Especially when according to your description, this stays underneath the same domain? (Or does it not?)

Comment: Sorry, that is at the customer's site, I can only just follow.

Comment: Well, then your customer probably has to just live with the fact, that current browsers take the security of their user’s data more serious, than they themselves do.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a HTTP request while using the HTTPS protocol.

This is because of the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Same-Origin Policy restricts you from interacting with other sources with different port, host, or protocol.

Here HTTP and HTTPS are two different protocols and hence you cannot perform the request.